# How to use re-run service in webdriverio?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I read from this doc: https://webdriver.io/docs/wdio-rerun-service/, that the rerun service is what I need to rerun the whole process when a test fails. I installed the rerun service and insert this in my code

```
const RerunService = require('wdio-rerun-service');
export.config = {
    // ...
    services: [RerunService, {}],
    // ...
};
```

but I can not find out how to insert the rerun in my testing files, would sb help me with this? Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

These changes needs to be done in wdio.config.js file.  You might already have selenium standalone server there. So do this....

After installing the 'wdio-rerun-service'

1. Insert this line at the top of file : **const RerunService = require('wdio-rerun-service');**
2. Update the service array like :

**services: [
[
'selenium-standalone',
{
logs: 'logs',
},
RerunService,
{
commandPrefix: 'VARIABLE=true',
ignoredTags: ['@known_bug'],
rerunDataDir: './e2e/custom-rerun-directory',
rerunScriptPath: '.e2e/custom-path-for-rerun.sh',
},
],
],**

Comment: Then trigger the generated script file ('.e2e/custom-path-for-rerun.sh') somehow. Note that it is designed for unix/linux os, cannot execute on windows.